# Calling a method with different values that can not be passed in the argument

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `method` which works for a single `record_type`. This `method` changes a column of dataframe with delimiter and convert it to multiple columns in the same dataframe.

```
ADDRESS_DETAILS = ["title", "forenames", "surname", "honours", "care_of", "po_box", "address_line_1", "address_line_2", "post_town", "county", "country", "occupation", "nationality", "ura_country"]
```

```
def applySchemaonDelimiter(delimiterDf: DataFrame):
    fixed_columns = delimiterDf.columns
    delimiterDf = delimiterDf.withColumn("variable_data_arr", split("variable_data", "<"))
    delimiterDf = delimiterDf.select(*fixed_columns, *[col("variable_data_arr").getItem(i).alias(k) for i, k in enumerate(ADDRESS_DETAILS)])
    delimiterDf = delimiterDf.drop(col("variable_data"))
    return delimiterDf
```

Now, the requirement is to make the the same method work for a different `record_type`, for which the `ADDRESS_DETAILS` would be replaced with `COMPANY_DETAILS`. Due to some constraints, we can not add one more argument in the `method` to pass the same.

```
COMPANY_DETAILS = ["company1", "company2", "company3", "company4", "company5", "company6", "company7", "company8"]
```

I tried 2 approaches, but succeeded in none. Could you please correct me, where I am going wrong with the syntax.

First Approch:
Adding a new column `column_list` based on `record_type` and using when required. But here, I faced probelm of adding `list` into a column. I tried `lit` and `array`. Both are wrong.

```
def applySchemaonDelimiter(delimiterDf: DataFrame):
    delimiterDf = delimiterDf.withColumn("column_list", when(col("record_type") == '1', array(COMPANY_DETAILS))
        .when(col("record_type") == '2', array(ADDRESS_DETAILS)).otherwise(None))
    delimiterDf = delimiterDf.withColumn("variable_data_arr", split("variable_data", "<"))
    delimiterDf = delimiterDf.select(*fixed_columns, *[col("variable_data_arr").getItem(i).alias(k) for i, k in enumerate(col("column_list"))])
    delimiterDf = delimiterDf.drop(col("variable_data", column_list))
    return delimiterDf
```

My second approach was to use `WHEN` with the `SELECT` based on `record_type` but could not.

```
delimiterDf = delimiterDf.select(when(col("record_type") == '2'), *fixed_columns, *[col("variable_data_arr").getItem(i).alias(k) for i, k in enumerate(ADDRESS_DETAILS)]
.when(col("record_type") == '1'),*fixed_columns, *[col("variable_data_arr").getItem(i).alias(k) for i, k in enumerate(COMPANY_DETAILS)].otherwise(None))
```

In both the cases, the syntax was not correct. Could you please help me with the same.

Thank you.